# How to pass value in an array with (:) in php?

Tags: php

I want to pass the value in an array with (:). I have values to I need to pass the value in array index and I need to use : and then encode/decode it but I am not able to do.

what I am trying but it not working for me:

```
$countArray = array("21F:22M:23F","31M:32F:33M","41F:42M:43M");
```

I want to pass the value like above line

```
$val1 = 21F;
$val2 = 22M;
$val3 = 23F;

$val4 = 31M;
$val5 = 32F;
$val6 = 33M;

$val7 = 41F;
$val8 = 42M;
$val9 = 42M;
```

I want something like:

```
$countArray = 
array("$val1:$val2:$val3","$val4:$val5:$val6","$val7:$val8:$val9");
```

So that I can get the output like:

```
21F:22M:23F,31M:32F:33M,41F:42M:43M
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 2):

You could use `implode`:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

```
$countArray = array(
    implode(':', array($val1, $val2, $val3))
    ... etc ...
)

print_r($countArray); # will output desired results
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also concatenate the values with "." as they are strings, for example:

```
$val1 = 21F;
$val2 = 22M;
$val3 = 23F;

$countArray=array($val1.":".$val2.":".$val3);
```

You can also do an iteration and parse the values when i%3==0, adding them to the array.